# PHP foreach table columns

Tags: php, html, mysql, foreach, html-table

I want to make it so that every 3 columns it forms a new row.  I am lost and can't figure out how to do this even after reading other posts.So I'd want it to be like

icon  icon icon

icon  icon icon

icon  icon icon

etc....

```
foreach($sMenu as $row) {
    $sClass = ($row['id'] == $aPage['id']) ? ' class="ui-btn-active ui-btn-custom"' : ' class="ui-btn-custom"';
    $sIcon = ($row['icon'] != '') ? ' data-icon="' . $row['icon'] . '"' : '';

    $sSiteRoot = get('site-root');

    $row['url'] .= ($row['url'] == '') ? '' : '/';

    $url = $sSiteRoot . $row['url'];
    $url = str_replace('(', '%28', $url);
    $url = str_replace(')', '%29', $url);
    $url = str_replace("'", '%27', $url);
    $sNavigation2 .= '<td><img src=". $sIcon .' . $url . '"></td>';
}
```

Comment: Sometimes the easiest way to do this is to have a variable keep track of how many times you run this loop (`$i = 0`).  Then, just check to see if the number is equal to 2 (`if ($i == 2)`) then... just add your `</tr><tr>` break (or whatever you need...) and reset the `$i` variable. Then, keep going through the `foreach` loop you have.

Comment: So where would I implement that into the code. would it be

Comment: I just put that comment into an answer below... and hopefully the code on that is easier to read. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes the easiest way to do this is to have a variable keep track of how many times you run this loop.  For example:

```
$i = 0;
```

Then, inside of the loop, just check to see if the number `$i` is equal to 2 (in this case.)

```
foreach($sMenu as $row) {

    // this is all your old code right here...

    if ($i == 2) { 
        // then add your </tr><tr> break or whatever...
        $i = 0;
    } else {
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Then, just keep going through the foreach loop.

This can also be done using the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) as a cleaner way to write this "row break" check (as shown by the other answers here.)

Comment: + incrementing $i at the end of each loop

Comment: This is just one way to do it... :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [modulus](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) (%) and output a new row if a counter is evenly divisible by 3:

```
$i = 0;

foreach($sMenu as $row) {
    $i += 1;

    $sClass = ($row['id'] == $aPage['id']) ? ' class="ui-btn-active ui-btn-custom"' : ' class="ui-btn-custom"';
    $sIcon = ($row['icon'] != '') ? ' data-icon="' . $row['icon'] . '"' : '';

    $sSiteRoot = get('site-root');

    $row['url'] .= ($row['url'] == '') ? '' : '/';

    $url = $sSiteRoot . $row['url'];
    $url = str_replace('(', '%28', $url);
    $url = str_replace(')', '%29', $url);
    $url = str_replace("'", '%27', $url);
    $sNavigation2 .= '<td><img src=". $sIcon .' . $url . '"></td>';

    if( $i % 3 == 0 ) {
        $sNavigation2 .= '</tr><tr>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of the "key" as index in array:

```
foreach($sMenu as $index=>$row)
{
    if(($index)%3==0){$sNavigation2 .= "<tr>";}
    //$sClass = ($row['id'] == $aPage['id']) ? ' class="ui-btn-active ui-btn-custom"' : ' class="ui-btn-custom"';
    //$sIcon = ($row['icon'] != '') ? ' data-icon="' . $row['icon'] . '"' : '';

    //$sSiteRoot = get('site-root');

    //$row['url'] .= ($row['url'] == '') ? '' : '/';

    //$url = $sSiteRoot . $row['url'];
    //$url = str_replace('(', '%28', $url);
    //$url = str_replace(')', '%29', $url);
    //$url = str_replace("'", '%27', $url);
    //$sNavigation2 .= '<td><img src=". $sIcon .' . $url . '"></td>';
    if(($index+1)%3==0){$sNavigation2 .= "</tr>";}
}
if(count($sMenu)%3 != 2){$sNavigation2 .= "</tr>";}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to check for every three items is to use [the modulo operator](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php), which checks for a remainder upon division.

Here's some psuedocode to get you started:

```
$counter = 0;
// start the first row
$html = '<tr>';
foreach( $sMenu as $row) {
    //add an item 
    $html .= '<td>' . $row[ 'id' ] . '</td>';
    //increment the counter, which is used to keep track of the number of items
    $counter++;
    //if $counter/3 has zero as a remainder, it's divisible by three
    if( $counter % 3 === 0 ) {
       //end the row after 3 items and begin a new one
       $html .= '</tr><tr>';
    }
}
//make sure there's an ending <tr> in case it ended on an odd number of items
$html = preg_replace( '/<tr>$/gi', '', $html );
$html .= '</tr>';
```